# Memory leak in vowpal wabbit initialisation

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, vowpalwabbit

We have an existing C project in which we are using vowpal wabbit. Our use-case is if new model updated in model directory reload the model  but every time after initialising we are getting memory leak(in valgrind).

Memory leak stack trace (from valgrind) and code snipped are below.

```
==31962== 7,093,114 (104 direct, 7,093,010 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1,655 of 1,660
==31962==    at 0x4A075FC: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:298)
==31962==    by 0x4F59F4D: boost::program_options::options_description::add(boost::program_options::options_description const&) (in /usr/lib64/libboost_program_options.so.1.59.0)
==31962==    by 0x5AAB82: add_options(vw&) (in testDebug)
==31962==    by 0x5BC95E: parse_source(vw&) (in testDebug)
==31962==    by 0x5BD877: parse_sources(vw&, io_buf&, bool) (in testDebug)
==31962==    by 0x5BE23D: VW::initialize(int, char**, io_buf*, bool, void (*)(void*, std::string const&), void*) (in testDebug)
==31962==    by 0x5BE4FA: VW::initialize(std::string, io_buf*, bool, void (*)(void*, std::string const&), void*) (in testDebug)
==31962==    by 0x53D658: load_vw_model_from_file (vw_predict_model.cpp:296)
==31962==    by 0x30858077F0: start_thread (in /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so)
==31962==    by 0x30854E570C: clone (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so
```

My code snipped -

```
//Declaration
vw* model;
pthread_rwlock_t vw_pmodel_rwlock = PTHREAD_RWLOCK_INITIALIZER;


//getting prediction 
double predict_vw_probability(string  vw_string) {
    double prob=-1.0;
    if (vw_string.length() > 0) {
        pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&vw_pmodel_rwlock);
        example *vec2 = VW::read_example(*model,vw_string);
        model->learn(vec2);
        prob = vec2->pred.prob;
        VW::finish_example(*model, vec2);
        pthread_rwlock_unlock(&vw_pmodel_rwlock);
    }
    return prob;
}

void load_vw_model_from_file(const char* model_file_path) {

    pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&vw_pmodel_rwlock);
    //destroying old model
    if (model != NULL) {
        VW::finish(*model);
    }
    char *vw_model_tem;
    asprintf(&vw_model_tem, "--link logistic --loss_function logistic -t  -i %s", model_file_path);
    std::string m_path(vw_model_tem);
    model = VW::initialize(m_path);
    if (NULL == model) {
        //Error 
    }
    pthread_rwlock_unlock(&vw_pmodel_rwlock);
    free(vw_model_tem);
}
```

We are thinking that `VW::finish(*model)` will take care of memory deallocation or is there any other way ? we  think memory leak is in libboost library , Please guide how can we remove memory leak.

Comment: try using --memcheck:track-origins=yes. This will tell you where the memory was allocated.

Comment: you'd better ask for authors assistance on projects github https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/issues